# How to save password using encrypt and decrypt in java using gwt

Tags: java, gwt, encryption

Hi i am working on project in java using GWT. I want to save password using encrypt and decrypt. which is the best way to save password with encrypt and decrypt in java? Any API shall i use? any help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt and scrypt. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database.

Comment: Don't forget to add [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to your passwords before hashing to guard against dictionary attacks. Also, use secure hashing algorithms such as from the [SHA-2 family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and especially not the widely used but very unsafe [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GWT-Crypto](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/) library

Usage is quite simple and is presented in following code:

```
    //this will be used for encrypting and decrypting strings
    private TripleDesCipher encryptor;  

    ...

    //creating key for encryptor
    TripleDesKeyGenerator generator = new TripleDesKeyGenerator();
    byte[] key = generator.decodeKey("04578a8f0be3a7109d9e5e86839e3bc41654927034df92ec"); //you can pass your own string here

    //initializing encryptor with generated key
    encryptor = new TripleDesCipher();
    encryptor.setKey(key);

    ...
```

The example functions using the encryptor can look like:

```
    private String encryptString(String string)
    {
        try 
        {
            string = encryptor.encrypt( string );
        } 
        catch (DataLengthException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InvalidCipherTextException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return string;
    }

    private String decryptString(String string)
    {
        try 
        {
            string = encryptor.decrypt(string);
        } 
        catch (DataLengthException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return string;
    }
```

Comment: _Please_ don't do that - client-side encryption is not a good idea, they even have an article on that in [their wiki](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/wiki/ClientSideEncryptionConsiderations). Please send the plain text password over _encrypted_ channel (SSL) and process it securely on the server (for example, hash it with bcrypt).

Comment: I don't say it's good idea 'cause you are right - just that this is a way to encrypt/decrypt string in gwt

Comment: It's a way to encrypt/decrypt in GWT _on the client side_. OP was asking for "the best way to save password with encrypt and decrypt in java", so not specifically on the client side - hence my remark. While your answer provides a valid way to encrypt/decrypt, it's a way that's strongly discouraged by the experts. That's similar to mentioning MD5 as a password hashing algorithm - technically correct (it's a hashing algorithm), but you should use stronger, salted hashing algorithms (i.e. bcrypt).

Comment: Thank u i want to use bcrypt so i have to include any jar? and from where for bcrypt

Comment: Thank u Igor Klimer for your information. I done it using bcrypt but i written   bcrypt code in server side means Using rpc call. so from client just i am sending the password text to server side using RPC call is my password secure??    And Then I am converting the password to hashing using bcrypt before saving the password to entity. so is my password secure??